# How do I find the directory of a csv using pandas in Jupyter Android?

Tags: android, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter

I've been looking for the .csv file from my directory, but pandas can't quite figure out where is it even when I already specified the entire directory. I use Jupyter Notebook in my android phone and I'm coding python but I'm still new to this.

Comment: Provide the code and also your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can add path over here....

filenames = glob.glob(path + "*.csv")